# 'onCreate' firebase cloud function error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am working on Push notifications on android via firebase cloud functions. My code is working absolutely nice when I use `onWrite()` condition, I am trying to implement this function for commenting, but in this case when when someone edit or like comment it produces a notification, so I changed it to `onCreate()` but now I am getting an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined`.

Here it is..

```
exports.pushNotificationCommentsPost = functions.database.ref('/post-comments/{postId}/{commentId}').onCreate((change, context) => {

    const commentId = context.params.commentId;
    const postId = context.params.postId;
    const comment = change.after.val();
    const posType = "Post";


    const getPostTask = admin.database().ref(`/posts/${postId}`).once('value');

    return getPostTask.then(post => {
        // some code
    })
});
```

I think there is a problem in  `const comment = change.after.val();` but I am unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
exports.pushNotificationCommentsPost = functions.database.ref('/post-comments/{postId}/{commentId}').onCreate((change, context) => {
```

into this:

```
exports.pushNotificationCommentsPost = functions.database.ref('/post-comments/{postId}/{commentId}').onWrite((change, context) => {
```

to work, since `onWrite` triggers when data is created, updated, or deleted in the Realtime Database. Therefore you are able to retrieve the data `before` and `after` it changed.

`onCreate()` triggers when new data is created in the Realtime Database. Therefore you can only retrieve the data that was newly added, example:

```
exports.dbCreate = functions.database.ref('/path').onCreate((snap, context) => {
 const createdData = snap.val(); // data that was created
});
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database

In your case, change it to this:

```
exports.pushNotificationCommentsPost = functions.database.ref('/post-comments/{postId}/{commentId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {

const commentId = context.params.commentId;
const postId = context.params.postId;
const comment = snap.val();
const posType = "Post";

});
```